# Not able to install any FreeBSD package

Tags: freebsd, pkg

I have been installing FreeBSD 12.0-CURRENT in a new desktop.

I lost the wifi connection while updating the system.

After that, trying to install `aterm` with the command:

```
sudo pkg install aterm
```

I got the following errors:

```
Proceed with this action [y/N]: y
Fetching aterm-1.0.7.txz: 0% of 70 KiB                                                                                 
pkg: cached package aterm-1.0.7: size mismatch, fetching from remote
Fetching aterm-1.0.7: 0% of 70 KiB                                                                                 
pkg: cached package aterm-1.0.7: size mismatch, cannot continue
```

I have noticed it does not work when installing other packages too.

What to do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems this is some sort of corruption of the packages cache.

To solve it I did:

```
sudo pkg clean
sudo rm -rf /var/cache/pkg/*
sudo pkg update -f
```

After that, I was able to install packages again.

I based myself on this thread from the FreeBSD forums [pkg 1.3.0: size mismatch cannot continue](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/47444/) with a similar problem.

Comment: All you need to do is run `pkg update -f`. No requirement to remove `/var/cache/pkg/*`.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not remember the specifics after all this time; I had serious problems dealing with that corruption case, and only deleting the directory seemed to fix it.